# "Access Denied" when trying to run a file that contains ".doc" in the filename

Tags: windows-7

A user has a folder which has given "Full Control" to "Everyone".

This user can move or delete a folder, but when they try to run a specific file in that folder they get an Access Denied error. The name of the file is `companyName.documentation.windows.exe`.

If we change the file name to something like `companyName.dacumentation.windows.exe`, it runs fine. It also works as expected if we fully remove the `.doc` section of the name.

The machine is a fresh install of Windows 7. Absolutely no idea what could be causing this. Any ideas?

Comment: We need more information about the configuration of the system.  This is a security permission configuration problem

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to any more information; don't know how the user is configured in AD or anything like that :/ I can close the question

Comment: If you want an answser, you need to locate that information, otherwise I cannot provide an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a permissions issue.  Given that you can simply rename the file and it works, this appears to be an issue with antivirus, group policy, security software, etc. that won't allow you to "execute" Word docs.

Whatever the cause, I bet it's got a rule that blocks filenames that contain `*.doc*.exe`.  It is a common tactic for viruses to be named something like `receipt.doc.exe`.  Since Windows hides file extensions by default, an executable with a Word icon could easily be mistaken by an untrained user for a simple Word document.

Try disabling your antivirus or other security software to see if it is the source of the block.  If not, you mentioned that this computer is on a domain.  Your sysadmin may have Software Restriction Policies or AppLocker enabled with a filename blocking rule like that.

Comment: Marking this as the right answer; I forgot to come back with an update but the client was able to confirm it's due to their Host Intrusion Prevention software which "doesn't allow double extensions". So it sees that `.doc` and `.exe` which trips it up.

Comment: So [AppLocker](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831440.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) basically? In a braod sense of the word, I consider a group policy or AppLocker rule to be a (security) permission problem, but thats just me personally.  HIPS would indeed explain this behavior.  ( I am not saying AppLocker is a HIPS, I am making two seperate comments, in a single comment ).

Comment: Seems kind of odd that an IDS would block "double extensions" by default, considering those are a common sight with .NET ClickOnce applications. I'll bet your sysadmin configured it that way deliberately ;-)